# Find difference in arrays based on values php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [to_email] => test@test.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [to_email] => test3@test.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [to_email] => testagain@gmail.com
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [to_email] => test@test.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [to_email] => test3@test.com
        )

)
```

I want to get the values from Array 1 which are different from the second array.

I have tried using -

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

AND

```
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

But both gave error like -

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

Outcome that I am expecting is

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [to_email] => testagain@gmail.com
        )
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a list of the email addresses to exclude using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column). We use the 3 parameter form to index that array by the email addresses as it makes it easier to filter with:

```
$exclude_ids = array_column($array2, 'to_email', 'to_email');
```

We can then use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter `$array1`:

```
$output = array_filter($array1, function ($v) use ($exclude_ids) {
    return !isset($exclude_ids[$v['to_email']]);
});
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [to_email] => testagain@gmail.com
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/m7sCk)

Note if you want the output array re-indexed to 0, just use

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like working Just couple of things-
1) I will have multiple count in $array and $array2 in future will it still work, and if the values are same?
2) Can we set the index to 0 instead of 2?

Comment: @Gagan what do you mean by "multiple count"? in terms of re-indexing see the last part of the answer.

Comment: All I meant was i this example the $array1 is having 3 values and $array2 have 2 in future there will be 20's of values in both arrays, so the solution will be dynamic. However, I think it should work. But just confirming

Comment: @Gagan yes, it will work regardless of how many values are in either array.